# Eclipse IDE: smooth scrolling with keyboard PGUP PGDOWN

Tags: eclipse, smooth-scrolling

Window 7.

In the Eclipse IDE, when I PageUp and PageDown, it jumps to the next bit of code without any scroll effect, which discombobulates me. How can I enable scrolling? Is this called smooth scrolling?

Answer (score 2):

It's not just Eclipse.

When you press the Page Up button or the Page Down button in Word, Notepad, or just about any other Windows application, you go to the previous or next section, respectively.

This has been standard Windows behavior since at least Windows XP.

Edited to add:

If you have a mouse wheel, you can get an effect that Microsoft calls smooth scrolling.  By rotating the mouse wheel, you can move the Eclipse editor up or down a few lines at a time.

But I don't think I've ever seen the same effect with the Page Up and Page Down buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Try this [Eclipse plugin](http://code.google.com/p/eclipse-mmb-scroller/) for smooth scrolling. Use middle mouse button, like when you smooth scrolling on internet browser.